# How to add the breadcrumb / address bar to ExplorerBrowser instances?

Tags: windows, winapi, interface, controls

Learning about the shell and its interfaces since a few days, I finally have managed to embed an `ExplorerBrowser` into a window of my .net application (I am talking about the [official ExplorerBrowser / IExplorerBrowser API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761909(v=vs.85).aspx) which has been introduced with Windows Vista, not the version from the WindowsAPICodePack).

The `ExplorerBrowser` works, but I couldn't figure out how to add the breadcrumb navigation / address bar. Actually, I am suspecting that the breadcrumb navigation / address bar is not part of the ExplorerBrowser at all. Given that, what would be the most straightforward way to add one?

Comment: The breadcrumbs bar is a private control to Explorer, Microsoft have not documented an API for it.

Comment: @JonathanPotter To be sure: A private control to explorer.exe (but not to ExplorerBrowser COM objects)?